# Restrict user from deleting a Table which is used in Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I have attended a SQL interview and I was asked how can you restrict the user from deleting a table that is used in stored procedure in SQL Server.?

Comment: You can GRANT users account specific privileges by table, so in your case you would not grant delete perm for that specific table to this particular user.

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated..I have searched in our site stack overflow and couldn't find it and so thought of posting it here.Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The question is too vague. This kind of question in an interview is designed to begin a discussion. The interviewer wanted to determine your understanding of many things here. There are just too many possibilities for how to "solve" this.

Comment: For example, you don't delete a table, you delete rows. Did they mean prevent the user from dropping the table or deleting any rows from the table. Is this for any particular table or only ones in use by a given procedure.

Comment: Thank u for your answer..i am .net developer and I just started learning SQL queries..

Comment: @SeanLange Agree..., But what do you mean you do not drop tables ;) https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @ntg I did not say you don't drop tables, I said you don't delete tables. And what does sql injection have to do with this at all?

Comment: @SeanLange Yeap sorry, was just making a poor joke... Also, as you write  drop and delete are different (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143915/what-is-the-difference-between-drop-table-and-delete-table-in-sql-server), so I stand doubly corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
--DENY DELETE access ON Table  
  DENY DELETE ON Table_Name to LogIn_UserName
```